# Adding an a value to a JSON file using ruby

Tags: json, ruby, jwt

Hi I'm using the following code to output a JWT token from a private key.

I'm looking to take the token value and output it as a JSON object.

The code works to output the key but I can't seem to get it to generate it as a JSON object.

Currently, it's just outputting the puts token directly into the JSON file and not treating it as a variable

```
require "base64"
require "json"
require "jwt"
ISSUER_ID = "ISSUER_ID"
KEY_ID = "PRIVATE_KEY_ID"
private_key = OpenSSL::PKey.read(File.read("/home/user/AuthKey_XXXXXX.p8"))
token = JWT.encode(
 {
    iss: ISSUER_ID,
    exp: Time.now.to_i + 20 * 60,
    aud: "appstoreconnect-v1"
 },
 private_key,
 "ES256",
 header_fields={
 kid: KEY_ID }
)

require 'json'
tempHash = {
    "key" => "puts token"
}

}
File.open("/home/user/web/jwt.json","w") do |f|
  f.write(tempHash.to_json)
end
```

Ideally I'm looking to have the JWT value outputted directly into the json file

Answer (score 1):

Please, try

```rb
tempHash = {
  "key" => token
}
```

instead of

```rb
tempHash = {
    "key" => "puts token"
}
```